# Marklogic: Element Range Index VS Element Word Lexicon

Tags: marklogic

I have an element which contains text value and I need to be able to search for the text content in it from the GUI application. 
I was reading the ML 5.0 documentation and I saw that I can use Element Range Index or Element Word lexicon on this element.
I would like to now which one should I use considering the fact that I need to

1. Search across 10 million documents which contains this element
2. Search speedily
3. use `cts:element-word-query`
4. Use search options where I am searching with `starts-with` and contains options.

Appreciate any help.

Harry

Comment: Can you post the options/queries you're using? A big part of the optimization is the query, not just the index.

Answer (score 3):

No extra range indexes or lexicons are needed. Searches for element text with `cts:element-word-query` use the universal index. The most efficient way is "fast element word search", which is enabled by default when you create a new database.

Further reading:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/text_index

Comment: I just noticed that you mentioned starts-with and contains matching, so you will also want wildcard support. Take a look at http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/wildcard for recommendations to support those. In some situations an element-word lexicon might help.

Answer (score 2):

One notable difference between an `element range index` and an `element word lexicon` is that the `range index` will store the string value of the element `("search terms")`, and the `word lexicon` will store individual word tokens `("search", "terms")`. Each facilitate different types of queries.

If you post a more detailed example of how you want to search the element, it will be easier to make a recommendation for a query/lexicon strategy.